# Javascript while or for loop that changes a string until a condition is met

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop

I am checking to see if a file exists and if so I want to do a javascript loop until the file name is okay to use.

I can't figure it out(var james is defined beforehand):

```
var i = 1;
while (filexisto(james+".ogg")) {
  james = james+"_"+i;
  i++;                           
}
```

For example, I want it to give me file names like this:

james.ogg

james_1.ogg  (james.ogg exists)

james_2.ogg  (james.ogg exists and james_1.ogg exists)

james_3.ogg etc...

right now it will do james_12.ogg if (james.ogg exists and james_1.ogg exists).
How can I structure my loop to give me what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use another variable to hold the original "james" string?

```
var i = 1;
var JAMES = james;
while (filexisto(james  +".ogg")) {
  james = JAMES+"_"+i;
  i++;
}
```

Comment: I'll try it. I'm concerned about(var JAMES = james = "james";) as james is a path that is a dynamic variable.

Comment: @Dave then there's no need to assing the value - see the updated answer